# Взять значение выбранного radio, если он видоизменен через css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть выбор из нескольких пунктов через radio, для красоты сам input скрыт, вместо него работает div с заданной красотой в css.

Проблема: Когда тыкаешь любой пункт, получается JS снимает значение с предыдущего выбранного, только при повторном клике на нужный вытаскивает его значение.

Как поправить?

```js
$('body').on('click', '.calc_reding', function(){
 var type = document.querySelector('input[name=calc_type]:checked').value;
  $('#result').html('Результат: '+type);         
});
```

```css
.form-inline .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
        min-width: 190px;
}
.calculator-inner .calc-title {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #19b09f;
}
#result {
 font-size: 2.4rem;
}
input[type='radio'] {
    display: none;
}
.radio {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.radio:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.radio>.radio-span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: 200ms;
    -moz-transition: 200ms;
    -o-transition: 200ms;
    transition: 200ms;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
}
.radio>.radio-span-discription {
 display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 color:#333;
}
.radio input[type='radio']+.radio-span {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
.radio input[type='radio']:checked+.radio-span {
    background-color: #19b09f;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 .001px 4px #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 .001px 4px #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 .001px 4px #fff;
}
.radio input[type='radio']:disabled+.radio-span, .radio input[type='radio']:checked:disabled+.radio-span { 
    opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
                                <p class="calc-title text-uppercase">Тип</p>
                                <label for="calc-type_1" class="radio">
                                    <input id="calc-type_1" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="1" checked><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type checked" data-calc_type="1"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">1</div>
                                </label>
                                <label for="calc-type_2" class="radio">
                                    <input id="calc-type_2" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="2"><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type" data-calc_type="2"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">2</div>
                                </label>
                                <label for="calc-type_3" class="radio">
                                    <input id="calc-type_3" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="3"><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type" data-calc_type="3"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">3</div>
                                </label>
                                <label for="calc-type_4" class="radio">
                                    <input id="calc-type_4" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="4"><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type" data-calc_type="4"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">4</div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: 1 вопрос. Зачем юзать `document.querySelector`, если вы уже используете джуквери?
2. сделайте так `$('body').on('change', 'input[name=calc_type]',` и будет вам счастье

Comment: А почему не срабатывало, почитайте тутка https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling вы сначала тыкали на ваш `div`, при этом инпут отмечен был еще старый, а потом произошел клик на лабел, который сменил отмеченый инпут уже

Comment: @Oleksandr Я тоже подумал именно про этот момент! Только забыл как с ним работать! Благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var formResult = document.querySelector('#result');
var formRadio;

function getValueRadio() {
  formRadio = document.querySelector('input[name=calc_type]:checked');
  formResult.innerHTML = 'Результат: ' + formRadio.value;
}
form.addEventListener('change', getValueRadio);
```

```css
.form-inline .form-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-width: 190px;
}

.calculator-inner .calc-title {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #19b09f;
}

#result {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

.radio {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.radio>.radio-span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: 200ms;
  -moz-transition: 200ms;
  -o-transition: 200ms;
  transition: 200ms;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}

.radio>.radio-span-discription {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: #333;
}

.radio input[type='radio']+.radio-span {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.radio input[type='radio']:checked+.radio-span {
  background-color: #19b09f;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 .001px 4px #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 .001px 4px #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 .001px 4px #fff;
}

.radio input[type='radio']:disabled+.radio-span,
.radio input[type='radio']:checked:disabled+.radio-span {
  opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <p class="calc-title text-uppercase">Тип</p>
    <label for="calc-type_1" class="radio">
                                    <input id="calc-type_1" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="1" checked><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type checked" data-calc_type="1"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">1</div>
                                </label>
    <label for="calc-type_2" class="radio">
                                    <input id="calc-type_2" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="2"><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type" data-calc_type="2"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">2</div>
                                </label>
    <label for="calc-type_3" class="radio">
                                    <input id="calc-type_3" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="3"><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type" data-calc_type="3"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">3</div>
                                </label>
    <label for="calc-type_4" class="radio">
                                    <input id="calc-type_4" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="4"><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type" data-calc_type="4"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">4</div>
                                </label>
  </div>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: самый подходящий для меня вариант! Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Используйте событие `change`:

```js
$('input:radio').change(function() {
  $('#result').text('Результат: ' + this.value);
})
```

```css
.form-inline .form-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-width: 190px;
}

.calculator-inner .calc-title {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #19b09f;
}

#result {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

.radio {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.radio>.radio-span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: 200ms;
  -moz-transition: 200ms;
  -o-transition: 200ms;
  transition: 200ms;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}

.radio>.radio-span-discription {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: #333;
}

.radio input[type='radio']+.radio-span {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.radio input[type='radio']:checked+.radio-span {
  background-color: #19b09f;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 .001px 4px #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 .001px 4px #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 .001px 4px #fff;
}

.radio input[type='radio']:disabled+.radio-span,
.radio input[type='radio']:checked:disabled+.radio-span {
  opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <p class="calc-title text-uppercase">Тип</p>
  <label for="calc-type_1" class="radio"><input id="calc-type_1" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="1" checked><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type checked" data-calc_type="1"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">1</div></label>
  <label for="calc-type_2" class="radio"><input id="calc-type_2" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="2"><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type" data-calc_type="2"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">2</div></label>
  <label for="calc-type_3" class="radio"><input id="calc-type_3" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="3"><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type" data-calc_type="3"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">3</div></label>
  <label for="calc-type_4" class="radio"><input id="calc-type_4" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="4"><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type" data-calc_type="4"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">4</div></label>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```js
$('label.radio').on('click',function(){
  var inputVal = $(this).find('input').val();
  $('#result').text(inputVal);
});
```

```css
.form-inline .form-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-width: 190px;
}

.calculator-inner .calc-title {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #19b09f;
}

#result {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

.radio {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.radio>.radio-span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: 200ms;
  -moz-transition: 200ms;
  -o-transition: 200ms;
  transition: 200ms;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}

.radio>.radio-span-discription {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: #333;
}

.radio input[type='radio']+.radio-span {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.radio input[type='radio']:checked+.radio-span {
  background-color: #19b09f;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 .001px 4px #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 .001px 4px #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 .001px 4px #fff;
}

.radio input[type='radio']:disabled+.radio-span,
.radio input[type='radio']:checked:disabled+.radio-span {
  opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <p class="calc-title text-uppercase">Тип</p>
  <label for="calc-type_1" class="radio">
                                    <input id="calc-type_1" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="1" checked><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type checked" data-calc_type="1"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">1</div>
                                </label>
  <label for="calc-type_2" class="radio">
                                    <input id="calc-type_2" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="2"><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type" data-calc_type="2"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">2</div>
                                </label>
  <label for="calc-type_3" class="radio">
                                    <input id="calc-type_3" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="3"><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type" data-calc_type="3"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">3</div>
                                </label>
  <label for="calc-type_4" class="radio">
                                    <input id="calc-type_4" type="radio" name="calc_type" value="4"><div class="radio-span calc_reding calc_type" data-calc_type="4"></div><div class="radio-span-discription">4</div>
                                </label>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```